# Does the story of Madhavrao Peshva contradict the BhavaghadGita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, karma, brahman, atma, gita

I would like to hear ideas on whether the story of Madhavrao Peshva (a brahmin-born who performed the duty of a warrior) **contradicts** the Gita's teaching that one should perform their own duty (and never another's)?

I theoreticise that it isn't based on Tilak's point of view. This is due to Madhavrao Peshva performing duty necessary of his time?

Comment: I am not sure in what circumstances Madhav Rao went to war but in times of emergency even a Brahmin can raise war. See this -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3157/can-a-brahmana-raise-a-war-or-kill-someone/21382#21382

Comment: your question is really whether varna is based on hereditary or based on one's own innate qualities and karma.

Comment: thanks for all the helpful information!